# download cloud code content & web hosting files

Tags: parse-platform, web-hosting, parse-cloud-code

ok, I blew up my repository, and murphy's law being what it is, plenty of other files were not 'versioned'. Nothing like screwing up to get rid of bad habits.

Is there a way to download the cloud code files and web hosting files from Parse ?

There's the solution to do that one by one, i.e. from parse.com/cloud code and slurp public files for the web hosting, but that's not exactly quick...

Has anyone faced this problem and found a workaround ?

thanks !
-A

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the new release of parse-cli, this is possible now. Make sure your cli is at least at version 2.2.5

Follow below instructions to download cloud code files on your new machine:

1. `parse new` then choose `e` for existing app, then choose your app. This will create a new project directory.
2. Browse to your project folder using command line tool
3. Use this command to download: `parse download [app] -f`. Replace [app] with the app name. Note that `-f` will override all current files in the directory

If you want to download code files to existing project, you can skip step 1.

---

The answer is taken from my answer to similar question here:
[Is it possible to clone existing cloud code already deployed on server side, through the Parse command line tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639470/is-it-possible-to-clone-existing-cloud-code-already-deployed-on-server-side-thr/32530001#32530001)

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately yeah the best way to do this if you don't have many cloud code files is to just go to your dashboard (at parse.com), under the 'core' tab would be all your cloud code files there.  As for your public files, you can get them by going to [appname].parseapp.com

Other than that, as of today, the CLI doesn't provide a way to pull your code and there is no access to download cloud code files otherwise.