# Is it possible to clone existing cloud code already deployed on server side, through the Parse command line tool?

Tags: parse-platform, terminal, clone, parse-cloud-code, command-line-tool

How can I clone an existing Parse Cloud Project files to my computer with the command line tool? I tried parse new and selected a project but it created a folder with new files, not the files that I already had in the Parse Cloud.

Note: I did not find clue regarding that point in the Parse cloud code documentation neither via Google.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note** this is now possible (2016), with new features at Parse.

---

**Response from a Parse engineer:**

"This is by design, which means that maybe we will include this feature one day. For the moment, the CLI tool cannot pull files from cloud code. The tool can only deploy code to Parse, it is not meant to be used in place of source control.

Thanks."

I spent a lot of time looking up an answer (on Google and the closed Parse forum) to this unanswered question. I finally had an answer from a Parse engineer, after having asked them on the Parse/Facebook bug tracker system, if it was possible to clone existing cloud code.

So I hope this answer will help you guys.

Answer (score 8):

With the new release of parse-cli, this is possible now. Make sure your cli is at least at version 2.2.5

Follow below instructions to download cloud code files on your new machine:

1. `parse new` then choose `e` for existing app, then choose your app. This will create a new project directory.
2. Browse to your project folder using command line tool
3. Use this command to download: `parse download [app] -f`. Replace [app] with the app name. Note that `-f` will override all current files in the directory

If you want to download code files to existing project, you can skip step 1.